# Conversion of template function pointer to bool fails

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

Consider the code:

```
void fnc(int, long, double*){}
template<int I> void f(int, long, double*){}

int main()
{
    bool a = fnc;  //(1) ok
    bool b = f<4>;  //(2) error
}
```

It triggers [an error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c7d5fdffd558992):

```
error: cannot resolve overloaded function 'f' based on conversion to type 'bool'
 bool b = f<4>  //(2) error
```

Why first case is correct, but second case isn't correct?

Comment: What error(s) do you get from the second? And do you *know* why the first is okay?

Comment: GCC says error, clang not: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/583eb08229602ad7 For comparison, assignment to `auto`-variable instead of `bool`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3015eda440d95221

Comment: VS2013 doesn't take too

Comment: The error seems a bug. I direct you to the error-message: ``cannot resolve overloaded function 'f' based on conversion to type 'bool' `` Which is somehow shown to be bogus by my change of using `auto` instead of `bool`, which compiles without warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are totally neglecting all the warnings, which are there to tell you that you're doing something very wrong.
Besides, you should use the `&` to get the function address.

Secondly, you're implicitly casting a function pointer to a `bool` variable.
Cast it explicitly to tell the compiler that you think you know what you're doing and you're sure about it:

```
   bool b= (void*)&ff<4>;
```

I just have to say that casting stuff to avoid errors and warning is a bad idea.
In most cases the warnings and errors are there to help you avoid loss of data and things that usually do cause runtime errors.